# Why is it hard to exercise with wearing the mask?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, home-experiment, biology

In today with COVID 19, we should wear the mask all day. My teacher in Korean high school said "If you want to play basketball, you could play with wearing the mask" to me. My friends and I wanted to play basketball, so we played basketball wearing a mask. But it was very hard to exercise with wearing the mask. I couldn't breathe well, because of the mask.

My mask(KF94-Korea filter 94) can block the particle of the average 0.4μm size over 94%.
But the O_2 is much smaller than 0.4μm. I think it is easy for O_2 to get through the mask and if so, I should breathe well wearing the mask. But I can't

Why is it hard, and ***how much is it hard to breathe?***

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is more of a biological question than a physics question. Try asking this question at [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com), which is a more appropriate place t ask such questions.

Comment: Who told you to wear the mask all day, you only have to wear it when you are close to other people and even that is diputed since the masks are a breeding ground for bacteria.

Comment: @FakeMod - the question is about physics, since it is about the resistance of air flow, but I agree that it sounds like a biology question at first sight. Nevertheless, Charlie's and Charles Francis' answers get the point from the physics perspective

Answer (score 7):

If you're doing sport your breathing rate will increase, if you have a mask on your face it will make it harder to draw in a full breath of air since the air now has to travel through the openings in the mask. There's also a chance that $CO_2$ is deposited inside the mask when you breathe out and so your next breath contains slightly more $CO_2$ (and so less $O_2$) than you are used to.

Answer (score 4):

Air is not a perfectly [inviscid fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow). There will be a viscous drag on the air passing through the mask. This arises because of the way the air molecules are constantly bouncing off each other, and off the fibres of the mask. The bottom line is you will have less air to breath when wearing a mask. Also, as Charlie say, the CO2 you breathe out will be less effectively dispersed.

Comment: Thank you. So if the air is perfectly inviscid fluid, is there no blocking?; Can I breathe as without the mask?